# Login User under a Group in Azure Ad using React Native

Tags: react-native, azure-active-directory

I am creating a react-native app that uses react-native-azure-auth as authorization. The login works as expected if the user is under tenant directory but for users under a group in azure directory the login asks for admin consent is there way to avoid this:-

[image: Admin consent screen]

Comment: Are you talking about the same user? If you add a user in Azure to the group, the user cannot be used normally?

Comment: I think it has nothing to do with whether the user is in the group or in the tenant. Check whether these users have the same azure ad role, and then check whether you have requested permissions that require administrator consent.

Comment: @CarlZhao thanks for your response the strange thing is i have an native android app that using msal library which  does the same thing but there the login does not show any admin consent screen only for the app developed using react native this shows

Comment: Try using the url that the administrator consent to: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/adminconsent?client_id={react native app client_id}`.  Request the URL in the browser and log in with the administrator account and consent.